# Nested position:fixed clipped with overflow:auto, but only in Webkit on Mac

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have two DIVs, main and header. Both are `position: fixed`. The top of the header places it above (in the negative top margin of) the main DIV, which has `overflow: auto` to allow for scrolling. The header is visible on all modern desktop browsers I've tested, except Chrome and Safari on Mac, where it's clipped (hidden).

This seems like a bug, but I don't understand why it would only affect Webkit-based browsers  on OS X.

Here's the code...

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">Partially clipped in Chrome and Safari on Mac.</div>
  Main content goes here.<br/>
  Main content goes here.<br/>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 42px;
  }
```

[Live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AVX7A/)

I found a few similar reports and suggestions about using `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)`. Interestingly, that doesn't fix it, but it does make the bug occur on Windows. [Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8QvvM/)

Any ideas?

Comment: i face the same problem too :(